# Implementation of the Gap Buffer algorithm as C++ container and iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

Please my review my implementation of the [gap buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) algorithm for efficient text editing.  I am particularly interested in the following areas:

1. Have I properly implemented a C++14 container and random-access
   iterator?  I found the spec to be a little hard to understand but I
   think I have everything required I hope. But in particular, have I
   implemented const iterators correctly?
2. There are a couple of places where I need advice on whether I've
   coded correctly/efficiently.  They are marked by comments.
3. Any other C++ stylistic advice.

---

This is buffer.h:

```
// Buffer -- manages text in a text editor (Interface)
//
// By Jaldhar H. Vyas <jaldhar@braincells.com>
// Copyright (C) 2017, Consolidated Braincells Inc. All rights reserved.
// "Do what thou wilt" shall be the whole of the license.

#ifndef _BUFFER_H_
#define _BUFFER_H_

#include <vector>

using BUFFER = std::vector<char>;

template<typename T>
class Buffer {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using iterator = BufferIterator<T>;
    using const_iterator = BufferIterator<const T>;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using size_type = size_t;

    Buffer();
    Buffer(const Buffer<T>& that);

    Buffer<T>& operator=(const Buffer<T>& that);
    bool       operator==(const Buffer<T>& that) const;
    bool       operator!=(const Buffer<T>& that) const;
    reference  operator[](difference_type n);

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

    const_iterator cbegin();
    const_iterator cend();

    size_type capacity();
    bool      empty();
    size_type max_size();
    size_type size();

    bool            deletePrevious();
    bool            deleteNext();
    bool            insert(value_type c);
    difference_type point() const;
    bool            pointMove(int count);
    bool            pointSet(BUFFER::iterator loc);

private:
    friend iterator;

    static constexpr size_t BUFFERSIZE = 80;

    BUFFER           _text;
    difference_type  _point;
    BUFFER::iterator _gapStart;
    BUFFER::iterator _gapEnd;

    void             moveGap();
    BUFFER::iterator userToGap(difference_type p);
    difference_type  gapToUser(BUFFER::iterator i);
};

template<typename T>
void std::swap(Buffer<T>& lhs, Buffer<T>& rhs);

template<typename T>
class BufferIterator {
public:
    // Iterator traits, previously from std::iterator.
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = typename BUFFER::difference_type;
    using pointer = typename BUFFER::iterator;
    using reference = typename Buffer<T>::reference;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    BufferIterator();
    BufferIterator(Buffer<T>& b);
    BufferIterator(const BufferIterator<T>& that);

    BufferIterator<T>&       operator=(const BufferIterator<T>& that);
    bool                     operator==(const BufferIterator<T>& that);
    bool                     operator!=(const BufferIterator<T>& that);
    BufferIterator<T>&       operator+=(const difference_type& n);
    BufferIterator<T>        operator+(const difference_type& n);
    BufferIterator<T>&       operator++();
    BufferIterator<T>        operator++(int);
    BufferIterator<T>&       operator-=(const difference_type& n);
    BufferIterator<T>        operator-(const difference_type& n);
    BufferIterator<T>&       operator--();
    const BufferIterator<T>& operator--(int);
    reference                operator*() const;
    pointer                  operator->() const;
    reference                operator[](const difference_type& n) const;

private:
    Buffer<T>& _b;
    pointer    _i;

};

template<typename T>
bool std::operator<(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs, const BufferIterator<T>& rhs);
template<typename T>
bool std::operator>(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs, const BufferIterator<T>& rhs);
template<typename T>
bool std::operator<=(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs,
const BufferIterator<T>& rhs);
template<typename T>
bool std::operator>=(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs,
const BufferIterator<T>& rhs);
template<typename T>
typename BufferIterator<T>::difference_type std::operator+(
const BufferIterator<T>& lhs, const BufferIterator<T>& rhs);
template<typename T>
typename BufferIterator<T>::difference_type std::operator-(
const BufferIterator<T>& lhs, const BufferIterator<T>& rhs);

template<typename T>
void std::swap(BufferIterator<T>& lhs, BufferIterator<T>& rhs);

#include "buffer.inl"

#endif
```

---

And this is buffer.inl:

```
// Buffer -- manages text in a text editor (Implementation)
//
// By Jaldhar H. Vyas <jaldhar@braincells.com>
// Copyright (C) 2017, Consolidated Braincells Inc. All rights reserved.
// "Do what thou wilt" shall be the whole of the license.

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
Buffer<T>::Buffer() : _text(BUFFERSIZE, 0), _point{0}, _gapStart{_text.begin()},
_gapEnd{_text.end()} {
}

template<typename T>
Buffer<T>::Buffer(const Buffer<T>& that) : _text(that._text),
_point{that._point}, _gapStart{that._gapStart}, _gapEnd{that._gapEnd} {
}

template<typename T>
Buffer<T>& Buffer<T>::operator=(const Buffer<T>& that) {
    if (this != &that) {
        this->_text = that._text;
        this->_point = that._point;
        this->_gapStart = that._gapStart;
        this->_gapEnd = that._gapEnd;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::operator==(const Buffer<T>& that) const {
    return this->_text == that._text &&
        this->_point == that._point &&
        this->_gapStart == that._gapStart &&
        this->_gapEnd == that._gapEnd;
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::operator!=(const Buffer<T>& that) const {
    return !operator==(that);
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::reference Buffer<T>::operator[](difference_type n) {
    return Buffer<T>::iterator(*this)[n];
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::iterator Buffer<T>::begin() {
    return Buffer<T>::iterator(*this);
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::iterator Buffer<T>::end() {
    return Buffer<T>::iterator(*this) +  size();
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::const_iterator Buffer<T>::cbegin() {
    return const_cast<const Buffer<T>&>(*this).begin();
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::const_iterator Buffer<T>::cend() {
    return const_cast<const Buffer<T>&>(*this).end();
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::size_type Buffer<T>::capacity() {
    return _text.capacity();
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::empty() {
    return size() ? false : true;
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::size_type Buffer<T>::max_size() {
    return _text.max_size();
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::size_type Buffer<T>::size() {
    return _text.capacity() - (_gapEnd - _gapStart);
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::deletePrevious() {
    if (_point <= 0 || _point > static_cast<difference_type>(size())) {
        return false;
    }

    moveGap();
    _gapStart--;
    return pointMove(-1);
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::deleteNext() {
    if (_point < 0 || _point >= static_cast<difference_type>(size())) {
        return false;
    }

    moveGap();
    _gapEnd++;
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::insert(value_type c) {
    if (_point < 0 || _point > static_cast<difference_type>(size())) {
        return false;
    }

    moveGap();
    *_gapStart = c;
    _gapStart++;
    return pointMove(1);
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::difference_type Buffer<T>::point() const {
    return _point;
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::pointMove(int count) {
    Buffer<T>::difference_type loc = _point + count;
    if (loc < 0 || loc > static_cast<Buffer<T>::difference_type>(size())) {
        return false;
    }

    return pointSet(userToGap(loc));
}

template<typename T>
bool Buffer<T>::pointSet(BUFFER::iterator loc) {
    if (loc < _text.begin() || loc > _text.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    _point = gapToUser(loc);

    return true;
}

template<typename T>
void Buffer<T>::moveGap() {

    // I used shrink_to_fit because I found that resize() was sometimes
    // giving me more space than I asked for.  Is that normal?  If so, is
    // this how I should deal with it?  Should I bother trying to reclaim
    // space if the gap gets too big?

    if (_gapStart == _gapEnd) {
        _text.resize(_text.capacity() + BUFFERSIZE, 0);
        _text.shrink_to_fit();
        _gapStart = _text.end() - BUFFERSIZE;
        _gapEnd = _text.end();
    }

    BUFFER::iterator p = userToGap(_point);
    if (p == _gapStart) {
        return;
    }

    Buffer<T>::difference_type n;
    if (_gapStart < p) { // point is after gapStart
        n = p - _gapEnd;
        copy(p - n , p, _gapStart);
        _gapStart += n;
        _gapEnd += n;
        _point = gapToUser(_gapStart);
    } else { // point is before _gapStart
        n = _gapStart - p;
        _gapStart -= n;
        _gapEnd -= n;
        copy(p, p + n, _gapEnd);
    }
}

template<typename T>
BUFFER::iterator Buffer<T>::userToGap(difference_type p) {
    BUFFER::iterator i = _text.begin() + p;

    if (i > _gapStart) {
        i += (_gapEnd - _gapStart);
    }

    return i;
}

template<typename T>
typename Buffer<T>::difference_type Buffer<T>::gapToUser(BUFFER::iterator i) {
    Buffer<T>::difference_type p = distance(_text.begin(), i);

    if (i > _gapEnd) {
        p -= (_gapEnd - _gapStart);
    }

    return p;
}

template<typename T>
void std::swap(Buffer<T>& lhs, Buffer<T>& rhs) {
    if (lhs != rhs) {
        lhs._text.swap(rhs._text);
        std::swap(lhs._point, rhs._point);
        std::swap(lhs._gapStart, rhs._gapStart);
        std::swap(lhs._gapEnd, rhs._gapEnd);
    }
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>::BufferIterator() : _b{nullptr}, _i{nullptr} {
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>::BufferIterator(Buffer<T>& b) : _b{b} {
    if (b._gapStart == b._text.begin() && !_b.empty()) {
        _i = b._gapEnd;
    } else {
        _i = b._text.begin();
    }
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>::BufferIterator(const BufferIterator<T>& that) : _b(that._b),
_i{that._i} {
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>& BufferIterator<T>::operator=(const BufferIterator<T>& that) {
    if (this != &that) {
        this->_b = that._b;
        this->_i = that._i;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
bool BufferIterator<T>::operator==(const BufferIterator<T>& that) {
    return _i == that._i;
}

template<typename T>
bool BufferIterator<T>::operator!=(const BufferIterator<T>& that) {
    return !this->operator==(that);
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>& BufferIterator<T>::operator+=(const difference_type& n) {
    auto count = n;

    // I don't like my code here.  The idea is a BufferIterator should
    // "skip over" the gap when incrementing or decrementing.  I feel like
    // I should be able to express it in terms of Buffer::userToGap or 
    // Buffer::gapToUser but I was unable to get that working correctly.

    if (count >= 0) {
        while (count--) {
            ++_i;
            if (_i == _b._gapStart) {
                _i += (_b._gapEnd - _b._gapStart);
            }
        }
    } else {
        while (count++) {
            --_i;
            if (_i == _b._gapEnd) {
                _i -= (_b._gapEnd - _b._gapStart);
            }
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T> BufferIterator<T>::operator+(const difference_type& n) {
    return BufferIterator<T>(*this += n);
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>& BufferIterator<T>::operator++() {
    this->operator+(1);
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T> BufferIterator<T>::operator++(int) {
    BufferIterator<T> tmp(*this);
    operator++();
    return tmp;
}

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>& BufferIterator<T>::operator-=(const difference_type& n) {
    return *this += -n;
}

template<typename T>
    BufferIterator<T> BufferIterator<T>::operator-(const difference_type& n) {
        return BufferIterator<T>(*this - n);
    }

template<typename T>
BufferIterator<T>& BufferIterator<T>::operator--() {
    this->operator-(1);
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
const BufferIterator<T>& BufferIterator<T>::operator--(int) {
    BufferIterator<T> tmp(*this);
    operator--();
    return tmp;
}

template<typename T>
typename BufferIterator<T>::reference BufferIterator<T>::operator*() const {
    return *_i;
}

template<typename T>
typename BufferIterator<T>::pointer BufferIterator<T>::operator->() const {
    return _i;
}

template<typename T>
typename BufferIterator<T>::reference BufferIterator<T>::operator[](
const difference_type& n) const {
    return *(_i + n);
}

template<typename T>
bool std::operator<(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs,
const BufferIterator<T>& rhs) {
    return lhs._i < rhs._i;
}

template<typename T>
bool std::operator>(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs,
const BufferIterator<T>& rhs){
    return lhs._i > rhs._i;
}

template<typename T>
bool std::operator<=(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs,
const BufferIterator<T>& rhs) {
    return !operator>(lhs, rhs);
}

template<typename T>
bool std::operator>=(const BufferIterator<T>& lhs,
const BufferIterator<T>& rhs) {
    return !operator<(lhs, rhs);
}

template<typename T>
typename BufferIterator<T>::difference_type std::operator+(
const BufferIterator<T>& lhs, const BufferIterator<T>& rhs) {
    return lhs._i + rhs._i;
}

template<typename T>
typename BufferIterator<T>::difference_type std::operator-(
const BufferIterator<T>& lhs, const BufferIterator<T>& rhs) {
    return lhs._i - rhs._i;
}

template<typename T>
void std::swap(BufferIterator<T>& lhs, BufferIterator<T>& rhs) {
    if (lhs != rhs) {
        lhs._b.swap(rhs._b);
        std::swap(lhs._i, rhs._i);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Incomputable If you believe that the code is obviously broken, then vote to close. Otherwise, please write an answer (even if it is short) rather than answering in comments.

Comment: @Incomputable Can you clarify?  g++ 6.0 with -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic didn't warn of anything and the code does work.

Comment: @Jaldhar, have you tried 1 < translation units (e.g. cppfiles in one compilation)? linker should complain.

Comment: @200_success, I’m not 100% confident, as I never did define functions outside of class definition. If I happen to e correct, I’ll make it an answer.

Comment: As far as I could dig, it seems like compilers mark them inline, but standard doesn’t require that. Sorry for the nitpicking.

Comment: @Incomputable fwiw I tried including buffer.h in a different .cc file and still no complaints from the linker.

Comment: @Jaldhar, just including them doesn’t force compilation. Template in itself is never “fully” compiled (e.g. type checks and linker are omitted/postponed), but instantiation might trigger that. Also, I had a case (I believe with clang), this didn’t work. I had to do something with the object.

Comment: @Incomputable: AFAIK `inline` is only necessary only fully specialized function templates (i.e. there is no template parameter left, so the function is uniquely declared). Example: `template<typename T, typename U> void f(T t, U u); template<>  inline /*required*/ void f<int, int>(int t); template<typename U> /* no inline required */ void f<int, U>(int t, U u);

Comment: @hoffmale, I’ve seen SO post about it, and it explicitly said that behavior is **non**-standard, but widely supported. May be some other section of the standard clarifies this.

Comment: @Incomputable ok so this time I tried creating a Buffer in a different .cc file and with a different template parameter and called some methods on it.  Still no complaints from the compiler.

Comment: @Jaldhar, it should’ve been the same type, as that will force the duplicate definition :) nevermind, sometimes I get worried about nonsense. I apologize again for this.

Comment: @Jaldhar: Is there a `friend class BufferIterator<T>` missing in `Buffer<T>`?

Comment: @hoffmale at the top of the private section there is `friend iterator` and I have `using iterator = BufferIterator<T>;` earlier.

Comment: @Jaidhar: Unless I'm totally blind or missed an edit, the top of the private section reads `static constexpr size_t BUFFERSIZE = 80;`

Comment: @hoffmale oh sorry somehow omitted it when I pasted in the code.  Fixing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Implementation

- `BUFFER` could be a defaulted template parameter. This allows for specifying different containers for storage.
- Any specific reason why `Buffer<T>::operator[](difference_type)` takes a `difference_type` instead of a `size_type` parameter?
- `Buffer<T>::pointSet(BUFFER::iterator)` takes an iterator of a private member - but `Buffer<T>` provides no publicly accessible member function which would return one.
- `Buffer<T>::cbegin()` and `Buffer<T>::cend()` are declared to return a `BufferIterator<const T>`, but would return a `BufferIterator<T>` instead.
- The `const_cast<const Buffer<T>&>` in `Buffer<T>::cbegin()` and `Buffer<T>::cend()` is weird. The called `Buffer<T>::begin()` and `Buffer<T>::end()` aren't marked `const`, so calling them from a `const Buffer<T>&` isn't possible anyways.
- The `BufferIterator<T>` constructor should probably accept a `const Buffer<T>&` instead of a non-`const` reference.
- `Buffer<T>::gapToUser()` reports incorrectly if `p > _gapStart && p <= _gapEnd`.
- `BufferIterator<T>::operator=(const BufferIterator<T>&)`: References (`this->b_`) cannot be reseated.
- The comparison operators of `BufferIterator<T>` don't check whether the underlying `Buffer<T>` object is the same.
- `std::swap(BufferIterator<T>&, BufferIterator<T>&)` doesn't check correctly for referential equality (`lhs != rhs` instead of `&lhs != &rhs`).
- `std::swap(BufferIterator<T>&, BufferIterator<T>&)`: I don't think it's intended to swap the contents of `rhs.b_` and `lhs.b_`. Did you want to exchange the references instead?
- Rule of 5 violation: You provide custom copy constructors and copy assignment operators for `Buffer<T>` and `BufferIterator<T>`, so you should also provide custom move constructors, move assignment operators and possibly destructors.
- Many member functions should be marked `const`.

## Naming

Many variable have very non-descriptive names. These could be improved for better readability (what tells you more: `b_` or `buffer_`?).

---

**EDIT:** To respond to some of the comments.

- `cbegin()` and `cend()`: The easiest and most correct way is to use overloads with `const` member functions. This requires `BufferIterator<T>`s constructor to take a `const Buffer<T>&` instead (shouldn't be a problem, as it doesn't change that buffer through the reference).

  ```
  template<typename T>
  class Buffer<T> {
      /* skipping stuff */

      // keep non-const begin and end
      iterator begin() { return iterator{*this}; }
      iterator end() { return iterator{*this}; }

      // add const overloads
      const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator{*this}; }
      const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator{*this}; }

      // make cbegin and cend const, forward to const version of begin and end
      // This forwards to the right overloads, since this is const
      const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin(); }
      const_iterator cend() const { return end(); }
  };
  ```
- "Reseating a reference" is another way to say "change the object a reference is referring to". This isn't allowed! References are seated (= set) once when they are initialized, and cannot legally be changed afterwards. If there is a need to change the pointed to object, pointers must be used instead.
- I have been thinking about `operator+(const BufferIterator<T>&, const BufferIterator<T>&)` and `operator-(const BufferIterator<T>&, const BufferIterator<T>&)` a bit more, and found that there is a use case (basically: determining `std::distance(it1, it2)` more easily), so keep them (I don't know how I overlooked that one when I wrote the original answer, sorry).
- Regarding move constructor and move assignment operator: Since you have a user defined copy constructor, the compiler won't generate a move constructor by default. Even if it were to generate the default move constructor by using `Buffer(Buffer<T>&&) = default;`, it wouldn't move any members that don't have a trivial move constructor themselves (e.g. `Buffer<T>::_text`).

  ```
  template<typename T>
  Buffer<T>::Buffer(Buffer<T>&& that) noexcept : _text(std::move(that._text)),
  _point{that._point}, _gapStart{std::move(that._gapStart)}, _gapEnd{std::move(that._gapEnd)} {
  }

  template<typename T>
  Buffer<T>& Buffer<T>::operator=(Buffer<T>&& that) noexcept {
      if (this != &that) {
          this->_text = std::move(that._text);
          this->_point = that._point;
          this->_gapStart = std::move(that._gapStart);
          this->_gapEnd = std::move(that._gapEnd);
      }
      return *this;
  }
  ```

Comment: _BUFFER could be a defaulted template parameter._ I did this and also BUFFERSIZE for good measure.  I renamed BUFFER to Container and BUFFERSIZE to N to match the style of the STL.

Comment: _why Buffer<T>::operator[](difference_type) takes a difference_type_ I thought it was required but I now see that it should be size_type so I changed it.

Comment: _Buffer<T>::pointSet(BUFFER::iterator) takes an iterator of a private member_  Yeah it should be a private method.

Comment: _cbegin() and cend()_  What is the proper way to implement this with a minimum amount of code duplication?

Comment: _BufferIterator<T>::operator=(const BufferIterator<T>&): References (this->b_) cannot be reseated._  I'm sorry I don't understand what reseated means.

Comment: _I can't discern any potential usage scenario for operator+(const BufferIterator<T>&, const BufferIterator<T>&) and operator-(const BufferIterator<T>&, const BufferIterator<T>&)._  They are required for a container no?  If not, I'll get rid of them as I don't use them anywhere.

Comment: _std::swap(BufferIterator<T>&, BufferIterator<T>&): I don't think it's intended to swap the contents of rhs.b_ and lhs.b_. Did you want to exchange the references instead?_  Yes I think you are right.

Comment: _Rule of 5 violation: You provide custom copy constructors and copy assignment operators... _  Actually I think I can get away with using the defaults for these right?

Comment: @Jaldhar: Added answers to most of your comments in the answer.